# iOS says not enough iCloud storage available despite no files

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

I am trying to back up my apps to iCloud via my phone as I am about to switch to a new phone. I turned on the iCloud backup feature, and pressed 'Back Up Now', and received an error:

[image]

However, when I log into my iCould account online I see this:

[image]

On my phone it shows this:

[image]

It says that I am using under half a GB for photos, despite that there are 0 files in the cloud. My questions are:

**If there is 4.5 GB of free space, how can I see what is taking up all the space that is preventing the backup?**

Old Phone is: iPhone 7 running iOS 15.7.8
New Phone is: iPhone 12 running iOS 16.3.1

Comment: @Alper Old Phone is: iPhone 7 running iOS 15.something (don't have access at the moment). New Phone is: iPhone 12 running iOS 16.3.1. The message I got was essentially 'not enough space'

Comment: Errors don't say "essentially".  What was the *exact* error?

Comment: @MarcWilson put a picture there which contains the error message.

Comment: Thx for the updates. The warning in the backup screenshot you added says there is not enough space, not "no available space". I think it would be better if you also updated the text in your post as well as its title.

Comment: @Alper Ive updated the post so there's no confusion for anyone. Screenshots tell all.

Comment: @Alper I would appreciate if you stopped editing my question. If you have useful information to help, you are welcome to help, but otherwise I would appreciate if you stopped with your edits.

Comment: Editing is part of the way the site works. You can always rollback edits you don’t agree with.

Comment: „Where is this other 4.5 GB of data that is used? How can I see this?“ -> This is free space, there is no data in it.

Comment: I've updated the the second part of the question to better reflect what I wanted to ask.

Comment: You are asking several questions here, can you please focus on the actual problem you want to solve here?

Comment: Updated question. One question only.

Comment: I'm still confused: Are you asking why you can't make an iCloud backup or how to make sense of the iCloud storage reporting you get?

Comment: In the second screenshot (from Apple ID/iCloud settings) there should be a link/option just beneath the storage bar (called "manage storage" or similar). Can you tap on it (may take a few seconds to load) to show the detailled iCloud storage usage?

Comment: It does show this, and I can see now that there is all kinds of app data that adds up to more than what is allotted by iCloud. This was kind of part of my original question as to why this data isn't displayed. I've basically just gone and nuked all the data these apps are allowed to store just to get a backup online. I think this is a perfect example of a bad question, and confusing answers. If you want to update your answer with that info I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I would rather help you to turn the question into something where the answers are actually helpful to you. Remember that we can‘t see your screens, so unless you share screenshots with us, explain what confuses you about them and clarify the question based on comments it will be hard to get good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What gets exactly included in a backup of your iPhone to iCloud depends on quite a few things including the settings of your iCloud subscription. The "[What does iCloud back up?](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428)" Apple support article explains how iCloud backup works and the list of things that might be included in such a backup.

Unfortunately, iOS does not tell you how much space your iPhone backup will take on iCloud prior to a backup unless you already have one (there are more options available once you have a backup to iCloud as described in "Reduce the size of your iCloud Backup" section of [this Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204247)). However, as stated in the first support article I mentioned above, pretty much all the phone set up info and the data files (not the applications per se) stored directly on your iPhone and not synched to iCloud is included in a backup.

One way of figuring out what might constitute a significant part of a potential backup, especially prior to the first time a backup is being taken like in your case, would be to check out the size of each app's data stored on your phone. You can do that by going to Settings->General->iPhone Storage and reviewing each app starting with the apps using the most space.

When you go into an app in that section, how much storage the app's executable and the data are taking up your phone are shown separately as described in the "[How to check the storage on your iPhone and iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656)" Apple support article. You can then consider deleting some of the data through that page or by going into the app itself or by deleting the app altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The message in the first screenshot indicates that there is **not enough iCloud storage available** to backup your phone. Basically this means that the backup would be bigger than the available space on iCloud (or, in other words, you need a bigger plan than the default 5 GB if you want to use iCloud Backup).

Comment: And the second photo shows that there is 4.6GB of free space, so I am confused as to what could possibly be in a backup that excludes photos and videos that would exceed 4.6GB of space. I also asked about why photos is taking up space since there are none, and also asked about why the apps are not showing.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid You can check Settings->General->iPhone Storage to see which apps need how much data.

Comment: Thank you , I have done that though. I'm using 4.2MB of space. How could this prevent a backup with the error message I have received?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid the 4.2 are the iCloud space used (the same as the 409 in the 2nd screenshot), not the iPhone memory.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are getting at. 4.2 MB not GB..

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Ah right, that's not the same. But both numbers (the 4.2 and the 409) refer to the free *iCloud* storage, not to the storage used on your phone or required for a backup.

Comment: I think you are confused. 4.2 MB is the amount of space that being used in iCloud and has nothing to do with the phone storage at all.  Please look at the photos more carefully.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid which of the screenshots shows the storage used on the phone?

Comment: As stated previously, storage on the phone is not part of this problem.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid An iCloud backup consists of data stored on your phone. If there is more data on your phone than free space in iCloud, a backup is not possible.

Comment: I don't know if I am being trolled, or what, but that doesn't answer the question. If you are trying to be helpful, thanks.